# Filling a 2*n room with two different tiles

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I came across a problem where I have to fill a rectangle having 2 rows and n columns. There are two tiles  one 1*2 tile and second a L shaped tile of larger sides having dimension 2 units and smaller sides having dimension 1 units.

I solved it through dynamic programming and am not pretty sure if it is working all right or not. If not what will be the correct bottom up code of this problem.
Below is the function snippet of my solution.

For the recurrence one column can be filled in one way putting the first tile vertically two adjacent columns can be filled in one way by putting the first type of tile horizontally one after the other. Three adjacent columns can be filled by aligning the two L-shaped in an inverted manner in 2 ways and four adjacent columns can be filled by two L-shape tile facing each other and the first type of tile lying horizontally in 2 ways.

```
int tileways(int n) //n=no.of columns of the rectangle.
{
    int i;
    int a[n+4];
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=0;
    a[2]=0;
    a[3]=1;
    for(i=4;i<n+4;i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2]+2*a[i-3]+2*a[i-4];
    }
    return a[n+3];
}
```

Comment: You have not explained this recurrence. I think that one could solve DP using three right-end configurations: |, L, Г,  or two  | + 2*L due to symmetry

Comment: @MBo edited. thankyou.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow dynamic length arrays, only some compilers support it, so consider `std::vector` here.

Comment: It seems for me that a[1] = 1, a[2] = 2, a[3]=5  (|||, |=, =|. two LL cases)

Comment: @tadman thanks. But I want to know if the logic is right. Or I am missing something?

Comment: Really hard to say without digging into this *considerably* more, which is a lot to ask. Showing code is a good first step. What's also important is showing us a) **how this function is intended to be used** with some demo code, and b) **what your expected output is** and what's specifically wrong with the output of this code.

Comment: @MBo I have shifted the array and what you are thinking of a[3] the answer is actually present in a[6] and will be 5 please check a[6] I think it will be much clearer. I took a[0], a[1], a[2] and a[3] as base cases so my array shifted by 4 units.

Comment: @tadman yes I know that.:-( I would not have ask if the question is present in other coding platforms. I saw it in a blog but there was no compiler to check my answer is correct or not. Rather I check in most of the coding platforms and is unable to find the question.

Comment: My advice is to break this problem down a bit more and write unit tests with a tool like [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) to ensure you've got your implementation right. Feed it use cases starting with the most trivial to more complex and see how it performs.

Comment: OK, it's clear now. But your code gives sequence not presented in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,2,5,11,22,47,101&sort=&language=english&go=Search), so perhaps it is not correct.

Comment: Right one: http://oeis.org/A052980    1, 2, 5, 11, 24, 53, 117, 258

Comment: @MBo ohh then maybe wrong. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using approach from my first comment.

`l[3]` configuration:

[image]

`L[3]` configurations:

[image] [image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int tileways(int n) //n=no.of columns of the rectangle.
{
    int l[20];//straight border
    int L[20];//extra square
    l[0] = 1; 
    l[1] = 1;
    L[0] = 0;
    L[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <=n; i++) {

        l[i] = l[i-1] + l[i-2] + 2*L[i-2]; 
        //add | to the last straight, = to the 2nd last straight, 
        //two cases of L to extra

        L[i] = l[i-1] + L[i-1];
        //add L to the last straight, - to the extra 
    }
    return l[n];
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
        std::cout<<i<<" "<< tileways(i)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/X9fp8e) result

```
1 1
2 2
3 5
4 11
5 24
6 53
7 117
8 258
9 569
```

For reference: [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A052980) `number of possible tilings of a 2 X n board, using dominos and L-shaped trominos.`

```
1, 2, 5, 11, 24, 53, 117, 258
```

Comment: What does L array represents precisely? I am not able to get that.

Comment: number of configirations with filled length i and jagged end (extra square from L-shape or horizontal bar at the end)

Comment: L[1] is 1. How come 1 column can be filled by 1 tromino?

Comment: The first column is filled, the second one contains one square

Comment: @ but is that not illegal as we are considering that no column can be filled whether half or not??Like the extra part goes to the next column which is violating the dp making the next column half filled.

Comment: All columns upto i-th one are filled completely. If (i+1)th column contains no squares yet, variant is counted in l[], if it contains one extra square - - variant is counted in L[]